# Using wildard with DOS COPY command corrupts destination file

Tags: copy, dos, wildcard

I don't understand the behaviour of the COPY command when using a wildcard.

I have a single text file in `C:\Source` called `mpt*.asm` and I want to copy it to `C:\Dest`. This is needed from a batch script, and I can't be sure of the exact name of `mpt*.asm` (it may be `mpt001.asm` for example). The destination name should be exactly mpt.asm.

If I use:

```
COPY C:\Source\mpt*.asm C:\Dest\mpt.asm
```

The file file is copied, but has a extra (`0x1A`) character appended to the end of the file.

If I use:

```
COPY C:\Source\mpt*.asm C:\Dest\mpt.asm /B
```

I don't get this spurious character.

If I don't use a wildcard, I don't get the spurious character either. It seems unlikely there is a bug in `COPY`, but this behavior seems unexpected.

Is there a way of doing this copy without resorting to using `/B`?

Answer (score 7):

I have never seen that before, but it does append an extra arrow character for me too.

You can work around the issue using `xcopy` instead.

```
echo f| xcopy C:\Source\mpt*.asm C:\Dest\mpt.asm
```

If you read `copy /?` it says

> To append files, specify a single file for destination, but multiple files
>   for source (using wildcards or file1+file2+file3 format).

So by using a single filename as the the dest, and using a wildcard in the source, it may interpret that as appending, which may be what the extra character is for, but as you aren't appending anything you can see it.

I'm only guessing but that may explain it.

Comment: You're right, this is due to `copy` working in append mode.  The extra 1A character comes from DOS; it used to be necessary for marking EOF on text files.  `/B` specifies binary files which avoids the problem.  http://www.tech-archive.net/Archive/Win2000/microsoft.public.win2000.cmdprompt.admin/2009-08/msg00010.html